# Pandas plot line for each unique value in a column (years)

Tags: pandas, dictionary, matplotlib

I have some data where time is grouped in decimal years, sampled at 0.02, so 50 samples per year.

I want to extract the data for each year and plot them on top of each other.

I've created a dictionary for each year by using integers:

`Year = df['DATE'].astype(int) # converts dates to years by integer`

`dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby('Year')))`

I'm now stuck how I would go about plotting a line for a third variable that changes with time (DATE) variable. What I basically want is a plot where y=variable and the x range is 50 samples (each year) and all years are plotted on top of each other.

Comment: have a look a `seaborn.lineplot()` with `hue` option

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try something like :

1 - convert your index to datetime : data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)

2 - plot your dataframe year by year : ex data['1992'].plot()

I guess the first step is the most tricky